# Android - How to show character count on top of EditText...?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, charactercount

In my application i am showing live character count below a TextInputLayout, using a class.
This is the class

```
public class CharacterCountErrorWatcher
    implements TextWatcher
{
private final TextInputLayout mTextInputLayout;
private final ForegroundColorSpan mNormalTextAppearance;
private final ForegroundColorSpan mErrorTextAppearance;
/*private final AlignmentSpan mAlignmentSpan = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE);*/
private final AlignmentSpan mAlignmentSpan = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE);
private final SpannableStringBuilder mErrorText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
private int mMinLen;
private int mMaxLen;

public CharacterCountErrorWatcher(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, int minLen, int maxLen)
{
    mTextInputLayout = textInputLayout;
    mNormalTextAppearance = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY);
    mErrorTextAppearance=new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
    mMinLen = minLen;
    mMaxLen = maxLen;
    updateErrorText();
}

private void updateErrorText()
{
    mErrorText.clear();
    mErrorText.clearSpans();
    final int length = mTextInputLayout.getEditText().length();
    if(length >= 0){
        mErrorText.append(String.valueOf(length));
        mErrorText.append(" / ");
        mErrorText.append(String.valueOf(mMaxLen));
        mErrorText.setSpan(mAlignmentSpan, 0, mErrorText.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        if(hasValidLength()){
            mErrorText.setSpan(mNormalTextAppearance, 0, mErrorText.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    mTextInputLayout.setError(mErrorText);
}

public boolean hasValidLength()
{
    final int length = mTextInputLayout.getEditText().length();
    return (length >= mMinLen && length <= mMaxLen);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    updateErrorText();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{
    //
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    //

}
}
```

And this is how i set this class on the TextInputLayout

```
text1.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new CharacterCountErrorWatcher(text1, 0, 100));
```

**UPDATE**
my Layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ppv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@color/logo_background"
tools:context="in.net.spectrum.frankstrade.SellActivity_2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#F7F7F7"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_camera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroller"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv1"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo1"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />


                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv2"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo2"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress2"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv3"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo3"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress3"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv4"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo4"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress4"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv5"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo5"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progress5"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:indeterminate="true" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add upto 5 images, each of max size 4 MB" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorCardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/cardView_padding">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:text="Select Category : "
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                            android:text="Select Category" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/sp_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorCardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/cardView_padding">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/input_layout_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/edt_title"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Title(maximum 100 characters)"
                                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
                                android:maxLength="100"
                                android:singleLine="true" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_desc"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:hint="Description(maximum 5000 characters)"
                            android:singleLine="true" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cb_stockimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Add this image you own to stock image"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="dummy"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="dummy"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next_sa2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corners"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And it is working fine. This is the result i get

[image]

As you can see the count is shown below the EditText. But when the softkeyboard pops up, the user will not be able to see the count. So i want it to **appear over the EditText**. I know it can be done by placing another textview over the editText and use the TextWatcher. But i want to use this method, since it keeps my layout file almost readable. I don't really get the concept of spannable string. So i don't know what to do in the CharacterCount Class. So what do i do to get the count to appear over the EditText(TextInputLayout)....?

Comment: share your layout.xml

Comment: layout file isn't going to be of any use. Since the only thing that is being used in this is the TextInputLayout. There is no seperate view or element for showing the CharacterCount. But i have attached it anyway... Check it out...  


input_layout_title : id of the textinputlayout

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand your question. But why can't you do it the simpler way? `since it keeps my layout file almost readable.` What does that mean? Your layout file has no need to change. Why not just use the TextWatcher with the `R.id.edt_title` and count the length of the string?